# Microsoft Azure and Glassfish

Tags: java, database, azure, glassfish

I am having a problem with Azure database and glassfish. Azure database is closing the connection with glassfish pool after 2 minutes. I found [the solution here](http://www.robblackwell.org.uk/2010/12/02/java-jdbc-to-sqlazure-connection-drop-workaround.html) but I am having a hard time implementing it.

where do I put this code ?

```
<Startup>
   <Task commandLine="Startup.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple">
    </Task>
</Startup>
```

Where do I put the file with this code ?

```
if exist startup.txt goto skip
time /t >> startup.txt
REM Workaround for JDBC to SQL Azure
REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters /v KeepAliveTime /t REG_DWORD /d 30000 >> startup.txt
REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters /v KeepAliveInterval /t REG_DWORD /d 1000 >> startup.txt
REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters /v TcpMaxDataRetransmission /t REG_DWORD /d 10 >> startup.txt
shutdown /r /t 1
:skip
```

Answer (score 2):

If you deploy Azure Cloud Service on Azure, you can use startup task to execute the cmd file and configure setting in .csdfg file.  You can follow those steps:

1. If you use Eclipse IDE to develop Java program, you can install the plugin "Azure Toolkit for Eclipse" from Eclipse Marketplace.

About Azure Toolkit for Eclipse, refer to the link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh694271.aspx.

After installed the plugin on Eclipse IDE, you can create a Azure Deployment Project, as to seen from the screensnap below.

[image]

2. Create a file named "Startup.cmd" and fill this PowerShell code into it.
3. Configure the startup task code into "ServiceDefinition.csdef" in your CloudService Project.

You will find the "ServiceDefinition.csdef" in the new project.
[image]

In the file, you can configure the startup task.
[image]

About the Startup Task details, refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh180155.aspx.

The startup task is a concept of Cloud Service on Azure. Cloud Service has two role concepts: Web Role, Worker Role. Startup task do some necessary things before roles start up runing, such as configure runtime environment, modify the registry keys.

About Azure Cloud Service, refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh124108.aspx.

For Java Developer, refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh690943.aspx

If you use Azure VM, I suggest you can modify the registry keys manually. I recommend you can refer to this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32044279/4836342