# Microsoft Azure Database and Glassfish

Tags: java, azure, jpa, glassfish

I have a j2ee web application deployed on glassfish 4.0.1 which I want to use with a Windows Azure Database.

The application uses JPA and eclipseLink.

If i ping it from the glassfish interface it works, so the properties I provide are ok.

If the application uses the database immediately after the server started, all goes well (it can retrieve/store data)

When the application tries to use the database after being idle for a while, I get an exception saying that the connection is closed.

If I flush the connection (from glassfish admin) it starts to work again, until it goes idle for a period of time.

So basically, as long as it executes database operations all works well, but if there are no database operations for a while, the next db operation will result in the exception.

I have found the solution but I am having a hard time implementing it. can someone help me please ?

Here is the link of the solution 
http://www.robblackwell.org.uk/2010/12/02/java-jdbc-to-sqlazure-connection-drop-workaround.html

or here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh290696(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Do you install glassfish on Azure VM or localhost? Is it Windows or Linux?

Comment: @PeterPan-MSFT it is a Windows Server 2008R, I installed glassfish on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, the alternative way to solve this issue is that you can create a crontab listener by using Java Schedule framework "Cron4j" or "Quartz" on your Java Web application. The crontab listener send a simple query(like "select id from t_XXX limit 1") with an interval less than one minute to keep database connection alive.

---

Press ”Windows+R” and Run  "regedit" . Check the registry keys "KeepAliveTime", "KeepAliveInterval" and "TcpMaxDataRetransmission" whether they exist in the registry tree path "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters".

If not exist in the path, you need to open the cmd window as administrator, and copy the below commonds into the cmd window to run them.

```
REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters /v KeepAliveTime /t REG_DWORD /d 30000
REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters /v KeepAliveInterval /t REG_DWORD /d 1000
REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters /v TcpMaxDataRetransmission /t REG_DWORD /d 10
```

Then, you can find them in the regedit, and test the issue.

Best Regards.

Comment: Try to add the registry keys and test the issue. Regards.

Comment: Thank you @Peter Pan MSFT, I changed the register and it seems to work now. Just one more question, how long the connection is alive ? 30 minutes ?

Comment: @EvanilsonAbril, As seen from the document, the connection idle more than 30 minutes will be terminated.

Comment: My application session also last 30 minutes, I am testing it since 2pm and, the problem apear again when the idle session is terminated I need to flush again so everything works again. This problem is killing me

Comment: @EvanilsonAbril Are you use Azure SQL Database? I think you can try to test the way by creating a crontab listener in your application to send simple query with an interval to keep connections alive.