# Glassfish server on Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, glassfish

I have a web app that has been developed using Glassfish server, and am looking to change hosts to Microsoft Azure.

The trouble is, Azure appears to not support Glassfish as a web container, and instead only currently offers Jetty or Tomcat.

Unless I'm missing something, I believe I will need to convert my server to run with one of the two above options, although obviously if there is a method to run GF on Azure that's the ideal option.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a concept named 'worker roles' which can be used to do this.

Have a look at this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dachou/2011/01/17/run-java-with-glassfish-in-windows-azure/

**More information:**

- [Microsoft Azure and Glassfish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32039861/microsoft-azure-and-glassfish)
- [GlassFish and Java EE 6 everywhere, even in the Azure cloud!](https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/glassfish_everywhere_even_in_the)

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that support has since been discontinued, that article was written in 2011. Either the resource I need is unavailable under my Azure subscription, or the resource is no longer available anymore.

Comment: Cloud Services (web/worker roles) have *not* been discontinued. But that's only one of several options.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking at Web Apps, which doesn't include Glassfish. But that doesn't stop you from simply spinning it up in your own VMs (or web/worker role instances, assuming you can install it in an automated way, in Windows).

Note: to deploy Cloud Services (web/worker roles) you're limited to Visual Studio and Eclipse (on Windows) for creating the deployment package.